# Transaction reference block, default is "head", configure to "solid" can avoid TaPos error

Tags: tron, trustwallet

I'm tring to use trust wallet core in c++ and sign a tron transaction but I got TaPos error.
I need change Transaction reference block from "head" to "solid".
how can do it?

Transaction reference block, default is "head", configure to "solid" can avoid TaPos error

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it, The problem not related to "Transaction reference block".
For broadcast must latest block of chain info set to block header in tron blockchian.

This api give latest block info(In testnet):
GET Api: https://api.nileex.io/wallet/getnowblock